Подписать точки после кластеризации данных
Python. Как подписать точки после кластеризации данных, названия точек должны быть с первого столбца файла CSV
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('classic.csv')
df.head()
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
X = df.values[:,1:]
X = np.nan_to_num(X)
Clus_dataSet = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
print(Clus_dataSet)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
clusterNum = 3
k_means = KMeans(init = "k-means++", n_clusters=clusterNum, n_init=12)
k_means.fit(X)
labels = k_means.labels_
print(labels)
df["Clus_km"] = labels
print(df.head())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 3], c=labels.astype(float), alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel('Октановое число', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Выбросы', fontsize=16)
plt.show()


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

отформатируйте код в вопросе как полагается. если ваш вопрос касается не кластеризации, а инфографики, уберите лишнее и добавьте датасет для воспроизведения.

Покажите данные, покажите, что у вас сейчас рисуется. Вы подписать хотите на оси или рядом с самими точками? В общем, нужно больше информации.
